# c# syntax help What 's coming after the constructor?

Tags: c#

```
public Butler(IWeapon weapon): this(weapon, new Communicate())
{}
```

What does this(weapon, new Communicate()) mean?

Comment: this is one for the vultures :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calls another constructor on the same type, passing in the `weapon` that was passed to *this* constructor, and a new `Communicate` object. I assume there is also something like:

```
// might actually be private
public Butler(IWeapon weapon, Communicate communicate) {...}
```

This approach is useful by allowing you to have multiple constructors, but only put the *code* in the most complex one. All the other constructors just pass the arguments (or defaults, as necessary) to the chosen constructor.

The chained constructor gets invoked *before* the body of the constructor that has the `: this(...)`

Comment: Is this also inheritance? It looks like "inheriting" a constructor.

Comment: @Camilo no; it is only calling a method in the *current* type; noting inheritance-related at all

Answer (score 1):

It calls a constructor in the same class but with different parameters, for example:

```
public class Test
{

  public Test() : this("Richard")
  {

  }

  public Test(string name)
  {

  }

}
```

Comment: In a case like this, an optional parameter would be the best, right?

Answer (score 0):

It means Butler extends an instance of the current class where the weapon object passed as the argument, and a new instance of the Communicate object are passed to the class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

it is calling another constructor with the signature Butler(IWeapon, ICommunicate).